# Saving custom post types post_meta over REST-API fails

Tags: custom-post-types, post-meta, rest-api

I try to save with wp-json my custom post types meta data but does not works in my case

I create my custom post type with [jjgrainger's](https://github.com/jjgrainger/PostTypes) class as it follows

```
$arguments = array(
        'public'       => true,
        'show_in_rest' => true,
    );

    $survey = new PostType('survey', $arguments);
    $survey->register();

    register_meta( 'survey', 'survey_data', array(
        'show_in_rest' => true,
        'single' => true
    ) );

    return $survey;
```

but when I save the following structure

```
 post: {
                    title: "Title",
                    content: "some content",
                    status: 'publish',
                    id: null,
                    survey_data: null,
                    meta: {
                        survey_data: [{'some': 'asdasd'}, {'some':'ssdfs'}]
                    }
                },
```

the post will be created but not the meta data

Comment: please check url : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35358088/save-custom-post-meta-not-saving-the-data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `register_meta()` function is defined like so:

```
function register_meta( $object_type, $meta_key, $args, $deprecated = null )
```

And the `$object_type` (as of now) has to be `post` for *all* post types. So use this:

```
register_meta( 'post', 'survey_data', ... )
```

See the `// {comments}` in the code below, which I copied from [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/extending-the-rest-api/modifying-responses/#read-and-write-a-post-meta-field-in-post-responses):

```
<?php
// The object type. For custom post types, this is 'post';
// for custom comment types, this is 'comment'. For user meta,
// this is 'user'.
$object_type = 'post';
$args1 = array( ... );
register_meta( $object_type, 'my_meta_key', $args1 );
```

### UPDATE

If you'd like to limit the meta to a certain post type, use the `object_subtype` parameter like so: *(that parameter was added in WordPress version 4.9.8)*

```
// Add survey_data meta support to `survey` post type in REST API.
register_meta( 'post', 'survey_data', array(
  'show_in_rest'   => true,
  'object_subtype' => 'survey',
  ...
) );

// Add survey_data meta support to `my_cpt` post type in REST API.
register_meta( 'post', 'survey_data', array(
  'show_in_rest'   => true,
  'object_subtype' => 'my_cpt',
  ...
) );
```

And as you can see, just duplicate the same `register_meta()` call for other post types. But the `$object_type` needs to be `post`, even for Pages (`page` post type).